# Is it possible to order lucene documents by matching term?

Tags: lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.10.3 with Java 1.7

I'm wondering whether it's possible to order query results **the matching term**?
Simply put, if my documents conatin a text field;

The query is

> text:a*

I want documents with **ab**, then **ac**, then **ad** etc.

The real case is more complex however, what I'm actually trying to accomplish is to "stuff" a relational DB into my lucene Index (probably not the best idea?).

An appropriate example would be :
I have documents representing books in a library. every book has a title and also a list of people who has borrowed this book and the date of borrowing.

when a user searches for a book with title containing "JAVA", I want to give priority to books that were borrowed by this user. This could be accomplished by adding a TextField "borrowers", adding a SHOULD clause on it and ordering by score) 
also, if there are several books with "JAVA" that this user has borrowed before, I want to show the most recent borrowed ones first. so I thought to create a TextField "borrowers" that will look like 
borrowers : "user1__20150505 user2__20150506" etc.

I will add a BooleanClause borrowers: user1* and order by matching term. 
any other solution ideas will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

I understand your real problem is more complex, but maybe this is helpful anyway.

You could first search for Tokens in the index that match your query, then for each matching token executing a query using this token specifically.

See https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermsEnum.html for that. Just seek to the prefix and iterate until the prefix stops matching.

In general it is sometimes easy to just issue two queries. For example one within the corpus of books the user as borrowed before and another witin the whole corpus.

These approaches may not work, but in that case you could implement a custom Scorer somehow mapping the ordering to a number.

See http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/03/12/using-customscorequery-for-custom-solrlucene-scoring/